# Db2 SQL: Select statement for merging multiple rows

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following data in my table:

| GRANTEE | TTNAME | INSERTALLOWED | DELETEALLOWED | UPDATEALLOWED | SELALLOWED | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | TABLE_A | Y |  | Y | Y | 2023-01-01 |
| USER1 | TABLE_A |  | Y |  |  | 2023-01-02 |

I want a SQL select statement where I can merge these two rows into one result, as I am interested in the permission a grantee has for a table name(TTNAME). The timestamp column should not matter/be ignored.

I want to have the following result:

| GRANTEE | TTNAME | INSERTALLOWED | DELETEALLOWED | UPDATEALLOWED | SELALLOWED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | TABLE_A | Y | Y | Y | Y |

I tried several selects, non of them worked. I always get the result as 2 separated rows. I assume because they have a different timestamp!?

I got:

| GRANTEE | TTNAME | INSERTALLOWED | DELETEALLOWED | UPDATEALLOWED | SELALLOWED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | TABLE_A | Y |  | Y | Y |
| USER1 | TABLE_A |  | Y |  |  |

I tried the following statements:

1. using Group by:

```
SELECT GRANTEE, TTNAME, INSERTALLOWED, DELETEALLOWED, UPDATEALLOWED, SELALLOWED
FROM AUTHTABLE
WHERE GRANTEE='USER1' AND TTNAME='TABLE_A'
GROUP BY GRANTEE, TTNAME, INSERTALLOWED, DELETEALLOWED, UPDATEALLOWED, SELALLOWED;
```

2. Using a self join:

```
SELECT A.GRANTEE, A.TTNAME, A.INSERTALLOWED, A.DELETEALLOWED, A.UPDATEALLOWED, A.SELALLOWED
FROM AUTHTABLE AS A
INNER JOIN AUTHTABLE AS B
ON A.GRANTEE=B.GRANTEE AND A.TTNAME=B.TTNAME
AND A.TIMESTAMP<=B.TIMESTAMP
WHERE A.GRANTEE='USER1' AND A.TTNAME='TABLE_A';
```

Is there a way to merge these two rows into one (by disregarding the timestamp)?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you try something like this: `select grantee, ttname, max(insertallowed) as insertallowed, max(deleteallowed) as deleteallowed, ... from authtable where grantee='user1' and ttname='table_a' group by grantee, ttname`?

Comment: Great! the MAX function seems working! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL is working:

```
SELECT GRANTEE, TTNAME, 
MAX(INSERTALLOWED) as INSERTALLOWED, 
MAX(DELETEALLOWED) as DELETEALLOWED,
MAX(UPDATEALLOWED) AS UPDATEALLOWED,
MAX(SELALLOWED) as SELALLOWED 
FROM AUTHTABLE 
WHERE GRANTEE='USER1' AND ttname='TABLE_A' 
GROUP BY GRANTEE, TTNAME;
```

Comment: If you can mark your answer as accepted, please do that. That way, others looking for a similar question can see an answered question.